# pickable objects disappearing (invisible) and reappearing on the world, how to fix?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Sometimes, after I pickup or move some object like a book or a cup or anything, one other object near it will vanish (completely invisible) and when I move items again it reappear, it is usually only a single (any) object that disappear...

What can be causing that and how to fix it as it is very annoying?

Comment: [This is a known bug](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bugs_%28Skyrim%29#Minor). Are you playing with the latest patches? If you're on PC, do you have the Unofficial Patches installed? (I believe they reduce but don't eliminate this bug.)

Comment: oh... I have it all already :(

Comment: I just left that comment to clarify your setup for other readers. I would *love* to hear about a fix for this, if anyone else comes along with an answer. Don't give up! :)

Comment: I thought, if there was a mod that fastly re-activates and de-activates physics on all items near the pickedup object. That would make them visible all the time; As I remember this trick is used on Fallout 3 and Fallout New Vegas! but, there, they are not promptly de-activated, so it messes the game somewhat (objects that fall thru table/ground etc).

Answer (score 1):

It's normally glitched out since items are can actually float unless one of the items or taken or holded. This also occurs it it's appearance. I would recommend trying to take items instead of holding the items [if that doesn't work, take the item near it].

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this in Skyrim is the physics engine itself, sometimes the items you place either do one of two things:

- De-spawn due to placement error whilst re-loading and implementing the game code (basically there's an original copy or code for each room and area, then there's a new copy based on what you alterd in the world, and sometimes the game gets confused and over-rides the new copy causing items to "disappear". It's an engine stability issue.)
- The game sometimes uses texture overlays instead of using physical barriers (it's easier) so the items don't actually "disappear", they fall through the maps visually perceived area. There are some mods for the PC that add more physical barriers under visual ones as a preventive measure. But other than that there is no resolve to this. It's something only the DEVs can fix.

Comment: I have lost hope also, they wont spend time on fixing old closed source games that are not making millions just because we (few ppl) want it...